# I cannot exit my webview app if i open more than two page in app. It will just go in loop and open the 1st and 2nd page and won't let me exit

Tags: android, android-studio

The code that I use for back button functionality is:

//set back button functionality

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() { //if user presses the back button do this
    if (webview.isFocused() && webview.canGoBack()) { //check if in webview and the user can go back
        webview.goBack(); //go back in webview
    } else { //do this if the webview cannot go back any further

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this) //alert the person knowing they are about to close
                .setTitle("EXIT")
                .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your `onBackPressed` logic works well for me. Can you please post your whole code related to WebView setup. How you load URL or set any other properties?

Comment: it work only when you open 1 page in app but if you open multple pages it will just move between pages and wouldn't allow me to exit.

Comment: I think you will need to add 1 more logic which is check whether this multipages or not.